# What iPad apps are available that support handwriting recognition?

Tags: ipad

What iPad apps are available that support handwriting recognition?

Are there any good iPad apps for taking notes that can recognize handwriting?

Answer (score 2):

You might like to checkout [Writepad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/writepad-for-ipad/id363618389?mt=8) - it sounds like it does pretty much everything you are asking. I've used it before, and found it worked pretty well. It's only $4.99US at the moment as well, so maybe a good time to give it  a go.

I also use [Plecodict](http://pleco.com) which is an English-Chinese dictionary, which has handwriting recognition for learning new characters (and an optical recognition mode as well) - just mentioning it because you didn't specify a certain language.

Good luck.

Comment: Interestingly, the Chinese handwriting keyboard option in IOS also recognizes latin letters.

Answer (score 0):

WritePad is definitely a good option. PhatPad, from the same publisher (Phatware), also does it, along with standard keyboard input and some drawing capability.